# Failed saving data from js to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I run the following js:

```
$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
  var saveId = $(".my_post_id").attr("data-id");
  console.log(saveId);
  $.ajax({
    url: "save.php",
    data: saveId,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(json_object) {
      console.log(json_object);
      $(".save_post").text("Data has been saved.");
    },
    error: function(json_object) {
      console.log(json_object);
      $(".save_post").text("Failed to save data !");
    }
  });
});
```

`console.log(saveId);` gives `248` which is what I would like to save.

PHP page

```
$post_data = $_POST['data'];
if (!empty($post_data)) {
    $file = fopen('data_save.json', 'w+');
    fwrite($file, json_encode($post_data));
    fclose($file);
    echo json_encode('success');
}
var_dump($post_data);
```

I get if I go to save.php i get the following and the button text after I click says **Failed to save data !**

```
Null
```

Comment: data: { data :saveId } try sending data like this

Comment: @VivekSingh nope, still failing

Comment: Try to sent the id like this:  data: { saveId }

Comment: @DiabloSteve nothing still

Comment: ok now works, actually removed dataType: 'json',

Comment: Change your `error:` signature to: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` and see what the actual error is.

Comment: If dataType:'json' added, try data:JSON.stringify(saveId)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: i just removed dataType all together and now works, don't really need a json anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it work by removing `dataType: 'json',`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
    var saveId = $(".my_post_id").attr("data-id");
    console.log(saveId);
    $.ajax({
      url: "save.php",
      data: {saveId:saveId},
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(json_object) {
        console.log(json_object);
        $(".save_post").text("Data has been saved.");
      },
      error: function(json_object) {
        console.log(json_object);
        $(".save_post").text("Failed to save data !");
      }
    });
});
```

Data should be passed in ajax like `{data:data}`